# How little food can I sleep on?

Tags: nutrition, diet, sleep

I've found that eating light dinners wakes me up early. However, I'm struggling to strike a balance between sleeping on a empty stomach and eating no more then I need.

I've tried and failed to sleep after having fruit for dinner, but a bowl of muesli has worked. [This](http://www.popsugar.com/fitness/What-Eat-After-Late-Workout-37320082#photo-37320082) looks like a good start.

Is there a certain amount of food I need to eat, or are there diets that can allow me to not eat too much, but still get a good night's sleep?

Comment: 70 kg. I find it difficult to sleep if i go to bed hungry, but light dinners help me to wake me up early because they leave me hungry by breakfast. I'm trying to eat enough so that i'm not trying to sleep on a empty stomach but still eating no more then i must,

Comment: It sounds like you're figuring out the balance on your own. If you're having trouble sleeping or waking up too early because you're hungry, then you should eat a little more for dinner.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not really answerable, as the amount of food YOU need for sleeping soundly is different than anyone else, and they can't tell you what you need.